# Typescript remove first argument from a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a possibly weird situation that I'm trying to model with typescript.

I have a bunch of functions with the following format

```
type State = { something: any }


type InitialFn = (state: State, ...args: string[]) => void
```

I would like to be able to create a type that represents `InitialFn` with the first argument removed. Something like

```
// this doesn't work, as F is unused, and args doesn't correspond to the previous arguments
type PostTransformationFn<F extends InitialFn> = (...args: string[]) => void
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand typescript much, but *InitialFn with the first argument removed*, isn't it completely another function?

Comment: In normal js if you want to remove the need to provide leading arguments you can use bind() to set arguments to pass when the returned function is called, ie `a=(b,c)=>{}; d=a.bind(null,6);` such that calling `d(7)`, `b` will always be `6` and `c` will be whatever the first passed arg to `d` was 7 in this case. Not sure what the ts syntax would be for this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you can do that in a more generic way:

```
type OmitFirstArg<F> = F extends (x: any, ...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never;
```

and then:

```
type PostTransformationFn<F extends InitialFn> = OmitFirstArg<F>;
```

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQQJwM7AIJoOYA8yAfFALxTJQQAewEAdgCYZQAUNAXFAIYMgAaKADpRPfBm4IGAMwhooABQCU5UtLkKASlAD87UcPF5JS1WVI7uDCADd5AbgBQT0JCgBlYD3rkoAbygMAHs4CGAAC2k8bj4QKABfFzdoAEkGJAQeABtkBj82LB8Ibi9ioUNjUyw0aIBtAF1zUltghCZXcGhFYKwAFTQ+DBlgtDgfBGCGPKJqOkYWKHTMnLzSCngkVEwcfCJiZycAeiOXaXo0GR4AY2g+iCxZ2npmVmXgLNyGUn8nKCgZNxkM5-jxuD1+oMGMNRuMPlMZiQQVAAEbg3rAAZDEZjCYIhj7ZHXdGQ7GwvHTAlIpxJFzZcIAgqmMr0IRgoLAWoMPBCNE1aLNAIJBxQOkM+hYbDce6PFLBGQA9YBP4AgQq9kcbj87lCECcbV4QX+BL-E5QYIAaxVaPYXA5XJ5UD1BqEAC99ZyBWohaajlAGMFgOarf9ibatZ6dU7OAwAK5wFHyI0ms0BoOWmlOIA)

Comment: You can use `never` instead of `any` for `x`: `type OmitFirstArg<F> = F extends (x: never, ...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never;`

Comment: @mofojed are you sure? when i do as you suggest, the extends condition results in an overall `never`. Instead i went with `unknown` :  `type OmitFirstParameter<F> = F extends [x: unknown, ...args: infer P] ? [...args: P] : never;`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a conditional type to extract the rest of the parameters:

```
type State = { something: any }

type InitialFn = (state: State, ...args: string[]) => void

// this doesn't work, as F is unused, and args doesn't correspond to the previous arguments
type PostTransformationFn<F extends InitialFn> = F extends (state: State, ...args: infer P) => void ? (...args: P) => void : never

type X = PostTransformationFn<(state: State, someArg: string) => void> // (someArg: string) => void
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8oGcD2BbCwAFgJYB2A5gFxTykhQC+AUE6JFAJKnHDHwA2AMVJRUACkwIk1OIggAaKADoV8AE7lM1SWrLkA2gF0AlKIB8UAG7ZiAExYB6B1CLFMUW9giZSAcmBQAO7YagDWivDuglBuUACupHGYELYRpLY0Gu6e3n4BAMYhat5g2Oku2C6E0GDFlsTYSZnkcfikwJis4NAACtiSACpqtJgAZiG4iA2kwgA80RAAHkjp7lw8fEKkFqgLyxCrUBJSEDIniipK6prUZKMQalA9psgW1nZQAPxHl9daTy83jYMtRSBBLA8WGxoAANURPfrAIYjcZqSa8MpzY5yM5yRQ4fAAQQ02mAugogKswIsTiOBIgxKoWDJekp7wyUCAA)

Answer (score 2):

I've landed on this question a few times now because I can never remember the name of the [`OmitThisParameter<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omitthisparametertype) utility exported from Typescript as of version `3.3`. The `OmitThisParameter<Type>` is not as generic as the solution posted by @georg, but has always been what I've been looking for when I stumble across this question. Hopefully someone else finds this helpful as well (at the bare minimum I'll see it next time I forget the name of the utility)