# Typescript remove first argument from function with overloads

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

I'm trying to remove the first argument from a function with multiple overloads.

I've used the type below from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58765199/2665931) to do this for functions without overloads but am having some trouble to get it to work with overloads.

```
type OmitFirstArg<F> = F extends (x: any, ...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never;
```

Example:

```
function func1(arg1: any, arg2: string): string;
function func1(arg1: any, arg2: number): number;
function func1(arg1: any, arg2: string | number): string | number {
    ...
}

type Func2 = OmitFirstArg<typeof func1>;
```

In this example `type Func2 = (arg2: number) => number`.

I need it to be:

```
type Func2 = {
    (arg2: string): string;
    (arg2: number): number;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is possible at the moment. At least not easily. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164 There are some complex and somewhat limited work arounds: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164#issuecomment-764660652

Comment: Overloads cannot easily be manipulated programmatically; see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options) for more info.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVKgqm), but it's yucky and only works for a small number of overloads.   I'm not sure if this should be its own answer, or if I should close it as a duplicate of other such overloads-are-hard-to-manipulate questions.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a nice and clean way to do this either at this moment. But for now I should be able to get this to work with @jcalz answer. Thanks!