# Typescript remove first argument from a generic function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to remove the first argument from a function that has a generic argument:
I would like something like this:

```
type GenericFunc = <T extends string | number>(c: any, p: T) => T;

type GenericFuncWithoutFirst = OmitFirstArg<GenericFunc> // = <T extends string | number>(p: T) => T;
```

I've found this related post: [Typescript remove first argument from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764853/typescript-remove-first-argument-from-a-function)

Which suggests:

```
type OmitFirstArg<F> = F extends (x: any, ...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never;
```

But this seems to remove the generic type inference when calling the function. I've made a demo of this in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAYgSwE4GdgEEsBzAV3ggDtgAeAFQD4oBeKWqCAD2EoBMcoAFAID6ALigBDCiAA0UMOIwUAZhCxQACgEpmjJavUwdAfkELNOpoxhRxFCKiwBuAFChIUAOKU1GAMZoJBR+zFB07Fy8-HhYSkRQAD5QFGQARmr0An7iUrLy4rSWjLSuLjwQfgA2EljQfogUeFBEPrEBQdlerf6Bwa7lVTV1DU0t9m29fgDqGMAAFogkwJi4wOJwSKgreISk5FTU3uM9HfSl9Y3AkqFjvu3BAgDeAL5yAEQSb1ouAPQ-kuIYnEXBcmqkbt17tNZgslttgAIPl9fv9UoDgLEKPEkil4OksEA)

Any help solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This cannot be done purely at the type level in TypeScript. If you're willing to drop down to the value level you can use [higher order type inference from generic functions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6PyRm) shows.  That may or may not work depending on your use cases.  Does this fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I noticed that replacing `(p: P) => R` with `<P>(p: P) => P` fixes it, although then you get warnings that `infer P` and `infer R` aren't used. It seems like the issue could be related to the lack of generics in the definition of `RemoveFirstArgument`, but the details aren't clear to me.